# Configure a live USB to install add repos and install software

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, usb

I4m comfortable enough with installing linux distributions on a computer but I always find myself having to go through the same process of forgetting which programmes I need to install. Additionally, I'd like to be able to give someone a USB and let them install linux plus the programmes Iknow they'll want.

Is there a way to make all of this automated( or as simple as following the normal installation assistant)?

If not, what is the simplest setup for an end-user to deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OEM install**

Best to unplug the HDD before proceeding.

Make a Persistent USB drive using mkusb.

When booting the USB you will see an option for OEM install (for manufactures).

Insert the target drive.

Follow the instructions and setup the drive as you like.

When done press the "Prepare for shipping to end user" button.

On your friend's first boot he will be able to add user name, password, etc.

The drive can be cloned to HDD if desired.

ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps) is a way of copying from one computer to another one. In a simple way:

Make a copy of your installed packages

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | sed "s/.*deinstall//" | sed "s/install$//g" > ~/pkglist
```

then a copy of your config  `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Save these two files on any  repository and use them every time you install new computer by running

```
sudo aptitude update && cat pkglist | xargs sudo aptitude install -y
```

Make sure you put your sources.list in your new computer's.

Comment: This fits in well with mkusb's new save/restore home directory function.

Comment: This worked for me, took a long time, crashed a few times, but as they say: all's well that ends well, thanks. Wondering if there is a way to list only the packages installed to casper-rw/upper ? All other packages are part of a read only squash file.