# Is there a simple way to create a custom Install Media that uses a customized Ubiquity installer?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, ubiquity, custom-distributions

I want to know how to create a Ubuntu based Install Media that has an customized Ubiquity installer that has custom branding and custom packages. I don't just want to create a ISO file of a system, I want an installer.

I also don't want to create my own mirror, just want to use the default Ubuntu mirrors.

(Pretty much I want to create a custom Ubuntu flavor for myself)

I can't find how to do this in a simple way anywhere. I AM READING the DebianCustomCD page on the Debian Wiki but it doesn't go over editing the Ubiquity Installer which is one of the main things I am trying to do.

Comment: It requires a bit of reading but the debian live scripts are by far the easiest. Your question is otherwise too broad and lacking detail on what change you want

Comment: @Panther I wish to create a "custom distro" of sorts that instead of just being a system just being made into an ISO.  So like how Linux Mint uses the Ubuntu Installer (Ubiquity) but customized it with custom packages, branding etc. I wish to that something like that

Comment: Read the documentation https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-live/ then ask if you have e a specific problem with a specific part. People are not goi.g to re type the documentation here

Comment: That is for a Debian-based live install. What I wish to do is to base it from Ubuntu, and use the Ubiquity Installer (not the Debian Installer)

Comment: No there isn't an easy way. I prefer the manual method myself: pick a minimal or server ISO, chroot it and add what you want. The minimal and server version have (almost?) no Ubuntu related pictures for instance. Maybe one imaged used during the boot process between grub and end-of-boot sequence.

Comment: @Rinzwind That sounds like a good idea, I might try that but I would prefer a graphical installer. (What I mean is I want SIMPLE not 1000 commands)

Comment: Well... a complex task often take complex executing of lots of simple commands ;-)  I can guarantee you one thing: you will learn a hell of a lot about the inner workings of the installer and Ubuntu. I made 2 answers on AU regarding editting live sessions and had a blast finding out how it works (I am a coder myself so its in my nature ;-) )

Comment: I LOVE LEARNING :D

Comment: @Rinzwind Your answer from a similar is good but I am looking to edit the branding of the installer itself as well, can you help me with that?

Comment: Keep looking .... the debian live scripts are in the ubuntu repositories and they install an ubuntu system. You really need to start by reading as your comments show. As you do you will have a more specific question and at that point we can better help. You have to find and edit the various themes and branding files

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that the Debian Live Scripts in the Ubuntu repositories did install an Ubuntu system, thanks for the information. I will start reading up more about what I am trying to do.

Comment: would it be possible to look inside of an iso file and edit what i want from there?

Comment: The debian live scripts allow you to add custom packages and files starting with a minimal install. They are easy to use and the documentation is solid.

Comment: @DiamondCoderMan no.

Comment: OEM Install: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049860/configure-a-live-usb-to-install-add-repos-and-install-software/1052808#1052808

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I don't want to create a OEM Image, I want to create a normal desktop install image. Thanks for trying to help but I am just looking for how to customize a installer image AND the Ubiquity Installer.